# How to get the location of a Maven dependency in a custom plugin?

Tags: maven, plugins, jar, dependencies, location

In a custom Maven plugin, during of execution I need to know the location of all dependencies of the Maven project, something like

```
/home/kider/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1/jdom-1.1.jar
```

I tried to get the dependencies one by one from MavenProject but I have access only to the GAV informations, but not to the file itself.

```
@Mojo(name = "testplugin", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.TEST)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter( defaultValue = "${localRepository}", readonly = true, required = true )
    private ArtifactRepository localRepo;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}")
    public MavenProject project;

...

    for (Dependency dep : this.project.getDependencyManagement().getDependencies()) {
        this.localRepo.getBasedir()
                    + File.separator
                    + dep.getGroupId().replace(".", File.separator)
                    + File.separator
                    + dep.getArtifactId().replace(".", File.separator)
                    + File.separator
                    + dep.getVersion()
    }
```

Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to add `requiresDependencyCollection = ResolutionScope.TEST,`...to the mojo annotation to get resolved dependencies...

Comment: What does this attribute change? Even so the dependency does not reflect the file path.

Comment: The next step is to use `Set<Artifact> artifacts = getProject().getArtifacts();` and use the `getArtifact().getFile()` ...I can recommend to look into source code of https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin and look into BuildClasspathMojo ...